# Has the CFD General Notation System Been Packaged as an RPM for SLES?

Tags: linux, sles

CFD General Notation System (CGNS) is a library used in scientific communities.  It is available via Sourceforge in its raw form.  I have found packages available for Ubuntu (http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/cgns-convert).  Although using tools like rpmfind.net, etc. have not turned it up for Red Hat or SUSE.  Specifically I am looking for an RPM for SLES 10.1 (IA-64).  The system is an Altix 450.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the [OpenSuSE software search](http://software.opensuse.org/search) to download the package; select SLED/SLES 10 from the dropdown. It's under "cgns". There may not be a package for your arch; if not, just set up an RPM build environment (install rpmbuild, basically) and then install the source RPM and tell rpmbuild to compile and build an RPM under your architecture.

Comment: And there it is: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/science/SLE_10/ In both i586 and x86_64.